# Move Gravity forms head DOM script to footer

Tags: gravityforms

I wonder if there is any way I can move the automatic Gravity forms DOM load script in the head tag to footer that starts with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">if(!gform){document.addEventListener("gform_main_scripts_loaded",function(){gform.scriptsLoaded=!0}),window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){gform.domLoaded=!0});var gform={domLoaded: ...
```

According to the GF support there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using ajax then you can use:

```
add_filter( 'gform_init_scripts_footer', '__return_true' );
```

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_init_scripts_footer/

Comment: Yes I have that function also but I use ajax so it wont work.